# Django QueryDict variable, passed via application-form-post, how to get variables?

Tags: python, django

I trying to get some variables from one server, this server isn't mine, and I receive the POST like these:

```
<QueryDict: {"'data[id]': ['83A0C50B5A0A43AD8F60C1066B16A163'], 'data[status]': ['paid'], 'event': ['invoice.status_changed']": ['']}>
```

Here is the code:

```
def get_iugu_retorno(request):
    d1 = request.POST
    d2 = d1.get['data[id]']
```

I need to get data[id], data[status] and event... but Django appears to get all these information like a flattern string instead a Dict.

How is the best way to solve these?

I also try to create a list:

```
d2 = d1.getlist('data')
```

and nothing...

I`m using Django 1.8

Answer (score 2):

This isn't form-encoded data at all, so you can't access it as if it is. It appears to be a form of JSON. So you need to access the post body directly.

```
d1 = json.loads(request.body)
d2 = d1.get('data[id]')
```

Comment: Isn't work, show these: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'   I think that maybe appears to be JSON, but isn't a really JSON, in contact with the owner of the server, he told me: I just send as a simple FORM POST, using content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: and don't forget your `import json`

Answer (score 1):

You are right in the assumption that `data[id]` is the name of the key, and not a list, but you are simply accessing the QueryDict the wrong way (`get[]`, it's `get()`). The following code works fine:

```
from django.http import QueryDict
qd = QueryDict('data[id]=83A0C50B5A0A43AD8F60C1066B16A163&data[status]=paid&event=invoice.status_changed=')
qd.get('data[id]')
>>> u'83A0C50B5A0A43AD8F60C1066B16A163'
```

Comment: I try that: d2 = qd.get('data[id]')   and show me: None

Comment: I think the problem is, way that string is passed, I notice you use & in QueryDict, but when I debug there isn't any & in the "string".

Comment: I just tried this in the django shell, and it worked fine there (Django 1.7 though, all I could access att the moment). But it appears I was a bit quick while reconstructing the QueryDict. The one you supplied was obviously not parsed correctly by the view, and I think you are right in your assumption about the `&` chars missing, or rather that you are not dealing with form-encoded data, as Daniel Roseman is suggesting.